How to understand Mary and Joseph fleeing to Egypt in light of Deuteronomy 17:16?
In light of Deuteronomy 17:16 and Jeremiah 42, how can I better understand Joseph and Mary and Jesus fleeing to Egypt?

Only he must not acquire many horses for himself or cause the people
to return to Egypt in order to acquire many horses, since the Lord has
said to you, ‘You shall never return that way again.’ - Deuteronomy
17:16 ESV


All the men who set their faces to go to Egypt to live there shall die
by the sword, by famine, and by pestilence. They shall have no remnant
or survivor from the disaster that I will bring upon them. - Jeremiah
42:17 ESV

There is no way they broke the Law in doing so, for the narrative is matter-of-fact in its telling. Perhaps both Deuteronomy and Jeremiah are better understood in context. Indeed, I’ve searched this forum to better understand the context, and I know that in Jeremiah the prohibition is mainly due to the instructions from the Lord in His declaration of wrath and mercy, but I have not yet been able to understand Deuteronomy in any other way than a prohibition on returning to Egypt. Is there something I’m missing here? Thank you for your time.

It would assist your readership if you were to quote the texts to which you refer.

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice.

Welcome to the site, and thank you for this question. The context of the 3 passages clears this up, especially when we see that hundreds of years separate all of them.
Here is what the first passage says: (always a good idea to quote texts within a question about them.)

"When thou comest in unto the land which Jehovah thy God is giving
thee, and hast possessed it, and dwelt in it, and thou hast said, Let
me set over me a king like all the nations which [are] round about
me... Only, he doth not multiply to himself horses, nor cause the
people to turn back to Egypt, so as to multiply horses, seeing Jehovah
hath said to you, Ye do not add to turn back in this way any more."
Deuteronomy 17:14-16 Young's Literal Translation

A key phrase is that any future kings of Israel must not go to Egypt to bolster their supply of horses. That would be for warfare, and Egypt would be considered an ally. Neither were any future kings to multiply wives to themselves, and gold etc, things that kings around, in pagan nations, did Big Time. Future Israelite kings were to maintain distance from such influences in Egypt. Obviously, that warning was not addressed to Joseph or Mary.
The next passage gives an example of a time when some of God's people disobeyed the command not to return to Egypt. In the time of Jeremiah the prophet, Israel was suffering defeat from the king of Babylon, due to their disobedience against God. Some survivors left in the land asked Jeremiah to seek Jehovah in prayer, to get an answer to their question, 'Should we flee down to Egypt?' They assured Jeremiah that, whatever the Lord's answer was, they would abide by it. Hypocrites that they were, they had already decided to flee to Egypt, and God knew it. Ten days passed before God responded to Jeremiah's request for God's decision, which was for the people to remain in the land, as Jehovah would deliver them from Babylon. Then God warned those enquiring of him that if they fled to Egypt supposing there they would find peace, the sword they feared would overtake them there, and famine, and death. The next chapters shows those hypocrites accused Jeremiah of prophesying falsely, and they forced him to go with them down into Egypt - where they suffered and died as they had been warned. (Jeremiah chapter 42 ff.)
Again, context shows that the warning applied specifically to Israelites some 550 years before Jesus was even born, and it pertained to a historic event regarding the king of Babylon attacking. Yet God warned the remaining people to stay put and not flee to Egypt at that time. They disobeyed, suffered and died.
That brings us to Joseph and Mary, shortly after the birth of Jesus, after the Magi had presented the infant with gifts. Joseph received an angelic dream telling Joseph to take his wife and child and flee to Egypt until being told when it would be save to return, "for Herod is about to seek the child, to destroy him." Matthew (the writer of this account) then notes they stayed in Egypt

"...till the death of Herod, that it might be fulfilled that was
spoken by the Lord through the prophet, saying, 'Out of Egypt I did
call My Son'." (Matthew 2:10-18 YLT)

That ancient prophecy is in Hosea 11:1. Matthew, under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit applies its second, major fulfilment to Christ. The N.I.V. Study Bible notes comment that Matthew "sees the history of Israel (God's children) recapitulated in the life of Jesus (God's unique[ly begotten] Son.) Just as Israel as an infant nation went down into Egypt, [Joseph and Jacob] so the child Jesus went there. And as Israel was led by God out of Egypt, so also was Jesus." [p,1414]
This, I suggest is how we are to understand Joseph and Mary fleeing to Egypt in light of Deuteronomy 17 (and Jeremiah 42, and Matthew 2).

Indeed, the question made the same mistakes many too-strict literalists make: a Bible passage says, in a certain historical situation, "do this right now" or "no, now it is not the time to do this", and they interpret it as "do this / don't do this, forever and ever". Many commands from God were situation-dependent, and it's not a good idea to ignore the context and assume that we must do that very same thing right now.


But he (the king) shall not have a great number of horses; nor shall
he make his people go back again to Egypt to acquire many horses, for
the Lord said to you, Do not go back that way again.

"Do not go back" is a reference to God's attitude toward those who lost courage and wanted to return to Egypt (e.g. Numbers 14).  During the Exodus, the Israelites were to continue on to the Promised Land. Deuteronomy is looking forward to the time of the kings, who were not supposed become dependent on Egypt.
By the time of Jesus, Egypt was no longer a threat. Hundreds of thousands of Jews lived there and elsewhere in the Roman Empire. The Jewish population of Alexandria was especially large.  Moreover Matthew describes Jesus' family as fleeing from the murderous intent of Herod I. Far from "going back" in the sense meant in Det. 17, they sought temporary refuge from an evil ruler. Indeed, Matthew describes them as being instructed to do so directly by the angel of the Lord:
Matthew 2:13

When they (the magi) had departed, behold, the angel of the Lord
appeared to Joseph in a dream and said, “Rise, take the child and his
mother, flee to Egypt, and stay there until I tell you. Herod is going
to search for the child to destroy him.”

Conclusion: Deuteronomy 17 warns the kings of Israel not become dependent on Egypt, just as God had willed the Israelites not to return to the land where they had been slaves.  In Matthew, God directly instructs Joseph to take his family to Egypt where they would be beyond the reach of Herod I. The two situations are not equivalent. Neither Jesus' family nor the large population of Jews living in Egypt at the time violated the instruction of Dt. 17.
